# When does a JavaScript project become a NodeJS project?

Tags: javascript, node.js

So, I know what the difference between `JavaScript` and `NodeJS` is, but I recently build a `NodeJS` emailer and I thought why is this a `NodeJS` emailer and not a `JS` emailer.

I have a `main.js` file containing all my scripts and I am using `nodemailer`.

So my question basically is, when did this become a `NodeJS` file and not just a plain `JS` file? What are the difference in files between the two? Does it have more to do with how you use the file? For instance where a `NodeJS` file will be used to make api calls and fetch data and a `JS` file will, in return, connect the backend to the frontend?

Any insights will be appreciated.

Comment: If you run the code in Node, it's a Node program. If you run it in a browser, it's not. There are other environments too, like microcontrollers that support JavaScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript is a programming language.

NodeJS (and a browser) are runtime environments used to run javascript code.

> but I recently build a NodeJS emailer and I thought why is this a NodeJS emailer and not a JS emailer

Assuming you *ran the code* in NodeJS, it was both.

> when did this become a NodeJS file and not just a plain JS file

There is no such thing as a "NodeJS file". NodeJS just runs javascript.

Comment: fully agree, but semantically one could argue thou that a web-App written in JS (without a node backend for i.E. routes) and initialized with `npm init` (generating a package.json for package mgmt - i.E. ngx, bootstrap or whatever) is sort of a node-project.. ;)

Comment: Thank you for your answer Jamiec. 

Yes, @iLuvLogix, that is exactly what I am also thinking. So if I only initialise it with npm, it is considered a Node project.

Comment: @Corné I was being a bit sercastic here: `npm != node`, but maybe Jamiec can give his 2 cents ;)

Comment: I think we're talking semantics here. A "node project" is simply some javascript you run on node. Does it become a "node project" if you've used node package manager (npm) - yes probably. But again, its just semantics. Javascript is a language, Node is a runtime.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript is a programming language.

Node.js is a JavaScript runtime.

Web browsers also include JavaScript runtimes (as do various other things such as Adobe Photoshop, Google App Scripts, and so on).

---

Until the Node.js became popular, the *vast*, **vast** majority of JavaScript projects ran in web browsers. Consequently, "JavaScript Project" is a term that is often conflated with "Browser based JavaScript Project" (which makes "JavaScript Project" an imprecise term that is usually better replaced with something more specific).

Comment: ..and npm is node's package manager ;)

Answer (score 0):

You mention [nodemailer](https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer). Naming and project description ("Send e-mails from Node.js") aside, the code contains lines like [this](https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer/blob/fca2041bdf33e4a6cb61929abb2503fa4e630219/lib/sendmail-transport/index.js#L3):

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
```

Since that isn't a standard ECMAScript feature but [a library provided by Node.js](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html), it's very unlikely that your code will keep on running if you uninstall Node.js from your PC, thus it qualifies as being a Node application.